# Social Plugin Alignment

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment, facebook-social-plugins

This is a site that i'm currently working on: [Site Link](http://luxury-decor.co.uk)

The problem I have is with the social plugins alignment. At first they were fine and showed one below the other (which is what I want) but now the facepile and twitter plugin just won't go below the facebook plugin. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it with different zoom levels in Chrome - with 110% zoom it's working fine, but at 100% they are next to each other. One simple solution is to wrap them into one div or even separate divs and then position these divs the way you like it.

Comment: That is perfect thank you! Don't know why I didn't think to just wrap all 3 plugins inside of another div...

Comment: Also, can I ask one more thing... Is there anyway to change the color of the border on the twitter plugin? I can add my own but the image positions over the border so its not even visible.

Answer (score 0):

@itzChris, It is perfectly possible to do this. I recommend you use Firebug, and see the classes of markup generated by the plugin. Then just customize them.